# Cannot read back serialized data using protocol buffer in C++ platform

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization, protocol-buffers

I have just started to use `protocol buffer` and try to make a minimal example to write and read back data. But I am failed to read back the serialized data.

### Sources I have used to make the example

[1](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial), [2](https://blog.conan.io/2019/03/06/Serializing-your-data-with-Protobuf.html), [3](https://riteeksrivastava.medium.com/protocol-buffer-what-is-it-41d1a3288e87).

### My Approach

#### Structure and Code to generate serialized data

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── lib
│   └── libproto_library.so # creted after the compilation
├── proto
│   └── message.proto
├── README.md
├── run_project.sh
└── src
    └── main.cpp
```

> - Points to be noted
>
>   - I have compiled the project using `cmake`. Ignored the cmake file not to make the post messy. If needed, I can provide.
>   - `build` folder is not shown in the structure. Generated header files by `protoc complers` are resided there.

`message.proto`

```sh
syntax = "proto3";
package message;
message Sensor {
  int32 humidity = 1;
}
```

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "message.pb.h"

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  message::Sensor sensor;
  sensor.set_humidity(68);

  std::fstream ofs("../bin/message.data", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
  sensor.SerializeToOstream(&ofs);

  return 0;
}
```

After building the project, I have used the generated `message.pb.h`, `message.data` and `libproto_library.so`.

### Structure and code to deserialize data

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── message.pb.h
├── lib
│   └── libproto_library.so
├── read_back_proto.sh
└── src
    ├── main.cpp
    └── message.data
```

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "message.pb.h"

int main()
{
    std::fstream ifs ("message.data", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
    message::Sensor sensor;
    sensor.ParseFromIstream(&ifs);

    int32_t read_humidity = sensor.humidity();

    std::cout << "humidity : " << read_humidity << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

After compiling this project, the generated executable file provides me the value of `humidity` is `ZERO` while I expect it would be `68`.

Looking for the suggestion to get back the correct value.

Comment: You're opening your input stream `ifs` with `std::ios_base::out`.

Comment: @Bert I have changed, `std::fstream ifs ("message.data", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);`. Still it is giving me zero. Am I using the syntax in  a wrong way !!!?

Comment: You should check if the input file was opened properly. I don't know how protobuf reacts when you give it an invalid stream, but it might fail silently and you get the default values for your message (0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encircled in a minor issue really. The path of `message.data` was wrong.

- Firstly, I was opening file with `std::ios_base::out`. Syntactical error. Already edited in the question though.
- Executable file is executing from `bin` directory
- `message.data` is located in 1 level up of `bin`, in the `src` directory
- Corrected code to read back serialized data:

  ```cpp
  #include <fstream>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include "message.pb.h"

  int main()
  {
      std::fstream ifs ("../src/message.data", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
      message::Sensor sensor;
      sensor.ParseFromIstream(&ifs);

      int32_t read_humidity = sensor.humidity();

      std::cout << "humidity : " << read_humidity << std::endl;

      return 0;
  }
  ```